# Attendence management

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I currently sending google forms to instructors to fill the students attendence.
Every time they enter a particular batch kids attendence,attendence is populted in a new row.
I want a every individual student attendence to be in their individual row.

```
                   Class1    Class2   Class3
```

Current Example : YAd Present
Yad            Present
Yad                     Absent

```
                   Class1   Class2   Class3
```

How I need is : Yad    Present  Present  Absent

I need assist and is there any other solution to get indvidual student details in a their row or is there any javascript or appscript code to connect forms and sheets to get it done.

Comment: That seems like a design questioin. We answer code questions not design questions.

Comment: Please provide a template of your spreadsheet to try to help!

Comment: Perhaps you could try going through an Apps Script quick start to learn the ropes. Here's a good one:https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#get_started